# Most of the apps crashing after editing platform.xml

Tags: crashes

I tried making writing to SD possible, so I edited `platform.xml` to add `<group gid=”media_rw” /> to “WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE“`.

When I rebooted everything started crashing. I cannot open any apps. It says it connects to Wi-Fi but cannot access the internet.

I tried:

1. Restoring original `platform.xml` - nothing good.
2. NAND backup -> restore to previous backup -> copy `.xml` from there and restore it - nothing good again.
3. Dirty flash the ROM which made me unable to even go to Recovery - had to re-flash TWRP.
4. Backup all apps via ADB and restore them on my previous backup, but all the settings are messed up.

Is there anything I can do to fix the `platform.xml` issue? What could be causing everything to crash like that? I restored the `.xml`, so why is it still broken?

Comment: Did you try digging into the logs? See [tag:logging].

Comment: What kind of logs? System? Boot? I doubt app specific logs would be of any use

Comment: Those Xml files are deep within the system anyway go into twrp then go into the mount menu. Next mount the system as read/write. Use the file explorer put the correct folder factory reset.

Comment: Do `logcat`, and search for kernel logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up resolving the issue by doing a factory reset and restoring all the apps from an old backup. Some loss but everything works at least.